# What does to smear energy means in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I'm reading about event selection for a particle physics experiment, english is not my first language, and there is this phrase I can not translate and understand: "The energy of the showers is found by smearing the summation of the ionizing depositions in argon. A smearing corresponding to a resolution of 15%$\sqrt{E}$ is applied"

At first i thought the word "smearing" meant like gather or adding but then is used as a noun.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nothing subtle.  It means taking the actual value and adding a random contribution (here presumably Gaussian, with standard deviation $15 \sqrt{E}$ %) to simulate detector resolutions.   By analogy to an artist who paints a clear design and then, while the paint is still wet, rubs it with a rag to give a blurred smear.

Comment: are you smearing a model (monte carlo), or are you smearing data? (I've smeared data in parity violating experiments to prevent quantization noise from swamping the signal...it's a thing).